# Interpolating values with datetime as an x-axis value

Tags: matlab, datetime, interpolation

I have two vectors, the x-axis values are a datetime vector and y axis values are a double vector. Some sample values are shown below:

```
x = ['16-Sep-2016 00:01:00','16-Sep-2016 00:56:00', '16-Sep-2016 01:56:00', '16-Sep-2016 02:56:00', '16-Sep-2016 03:56:00'];
y = [77, 76.6, 77.5, 76.6, 76.5];
```

Here the x-axis values are roughly hourly. and I want every 10 minute intervals. I created a new sampled time vector (x_resampled) and tried to do 1-D interpolation as such:

```
y_resampled = interp1(x,y,x_resampled);
```

But this doesn't work and gives me an error that 'X must be a vector of numeric coordinates' so I can't use this function. I would appreciate it if anyone has any ideas on how to interpolate the values.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to convert your vector x to serial date number, you can use `datenum`

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't even know there is a such a thing at datenum. Makes sense now.